# Custom set of filters in the DataGrid

Tags: filter, datagrid, blazor, radzen

I want to show only specific set of filters in the Radzen DataGrid. For example, I want to hide "Is null" and "Is not null" from the filter operators set. Or, broader question, I want to specify my custom set of filter operators for each type. Any possibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done through inheriting from the RadzenDataGridColumn and overriding its GetFilterOperators method, as shown in the [Radzen tutorial](https://blazor.radzen.com/datagrid-filter-api) (check "MyCustomDataGridColumn.razor" tab). I'll just copy the example code from there, adding only a little changings:

```
@using Radzen
@typeparam TItem
@inherits RadzenDataGridColumn<TItem>

@code {
public override IEnumerable<FilterOperator> GetFilterOperators()
{
    var operators = base.GetFilterOperators();

    if (FilterPropertyType == typeof(DateTime?))
    {
        operators = 
            operators.Where(o => o != FilterOperator.IsNull && o != FilterOperator.IsNotNull);
        // or using patterns
        // operators = 
        //  operators.Where(o => o is not (FilterOperator.IsNull or FilterOperator.IsNotNull);
    }

    return operators;
}

public override bool ShowTimeForDateTimeFilter()
{
    return false;
}
```

}